# How can plot Results of the Friedman-Nemenyi test using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I calculated results of the Friedman-Nemenyi test for 12 datasets and 11 classifiers and I want to plot the results like the following figure
[image]

I computed all the requirement CD is single number (shown as CD in the figure), list of classifiers (C4.5+m+cf, C4.5+m and so) and the value of mean ranked (which on x axis)

Many thanks in advance

[2](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.141.3142&rep=rep1&type=pdf): [enter link description here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.141.3142&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to reproduce the above plot, you may just set 3 of the spines of a normal plot to invisible and then add the respective elements to the plot.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# input data
cd = 1.2
c = 3.2
ccf = 2.8
cmcf = 1.9
cm = 2.05

limits=(4,1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,1.8))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, right=0.8)

# set up plot
ax.set_xlim(limits)
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
ax.spines['top'].set_position(('axes', 0.6))
#ax.xaxis.tick_top()
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
for pos in ["bottom", "left", "right"]:
    ax.spines[pos].set_visible(False)

# CD bar
ax.plot([limits[0],limits[0]-cd], [.9,.9], color="k")
ax.plot([limits[0],limits[0]], [.9-0.03,.9+0.03], color="k")
ax.plot([limits[0]-cd,limits[0]-cd], [.9-0.03,.9+0.03], color="k") 
ax.text(limits[0]-cd/2., 0.92, "CD", ha="center", va="bottom") 

# annotations
bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-",connectionstyle="angle,angleA=0,angleB=90")
kw = dict(xycoords='data',textcoords="axes fraction",
          arrowprops=arrowprops, bbox=bbox_props, va="center")
ax.annotate("C4.5", xy=(c, 0.6), xytext=(0,0.25),ha="right",  **kw)
ax.annotate("C4.5+cf", xy=(ccf, 0.6), xytext=(0,0),ha="right",  **kw)
ax.annotate("C4.5+m+cf", xy=(cmcf, 0.6), xytext=(1.,0.25),ha="left",  **kw)
ax.annotate("C4.5+m", xy=(cm, 0.6), xytext=(1.,0),ha="left",  **kw)

#bars
ax.plot([ccf,c],[0.55,0.55], color="k", lw=3)
ax.plot([ccf,cmcf],[0.48,0.48], color="k", lw=3)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import Orange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
names = ["first", "third", "second", "fourth" ]
avranks =  [1.9, 3.2, 2.8, 3.3 ]
cd = Orange.evaluation.compute_CD(avranks, 30) #tested on 30 datasets
Orange.evaluation.graph_ranks(avranks, names, cd=cd, width=6, textspace=1.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Code from orange site.

Comment: The `compute_CD` method is deprecated in the latest Orange3 package.

Answer (score 0):

The `compute_CD` method is now deprecated in the latest Orange3 package. However, I found the [autorank](https://github.com/sherbold/autorank) package which is extremely helpful.

To perform the Nemenyi post-hoc test, you need to have a dataframe of various models and its corresponding evaluation results (an excerpt from my personal project):

|  | Model 1 | Model 2 | Model 3 | Model 4 | Model 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Metric 1 | 0.01 | 0.02 | 0.03 | 0.04 | 0.05 |
| Metric 2 | 0.05 | 0.04 | 0.03 | 0.02 | 0.01 |
| Metric 3 | 0.04 | 0.02 | 0.01 | 0.05 | 0.03 |

Here, you can see that the evaluation results are in rows, and models in the columns.

Pass this dataframe to autorank and plot the critical distance plot:

```
from autorank import autorank, plot_stats

result = autorank(df, alpha=0.05, verbose=False, order='ascending')
plot_stats(result)
plt.show()
```

Notes:

1. Use `order='ascending'` if the metrics are error based (smaller the better)
2. Your dataframe format must be models in the columns and evaluation metrics in the rows.